# How to add bricks to curved surface

Tags: modeling

I'm making a low poly with bridge with bricks on it and I'm not sure how to put the bricks on the curved surface easily. If I do it manually I would have to rotate each brick manually which seems redundant.
Here is a picture of the Bridge I am working on
[image]

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to make
[image]

Comment: Do you really need that as real geometry? Paint those bricks with textures. Look at Grant Abbitt videos on his painting lowpoly game models, it's similar style, like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOSKGO5QZls

Comment: Yeah maybe I don't, thanks!

Comment: You can model bricks create a curve along the bridge and create a array of blocks following that curve yt link: https://youtu.be/aZN0AAIlrHI